# Find the last row with data and autoFit everything

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm creating an extract in Excel with data from a datatable in my vb.net application. It extracts everything correctly. Now I'm trying to do a bit of design work to make it all pretty. It seems like I'm having an issue with probably something every easy but for some reason I keep getting the below error.

> Public member 'XlDirection' on type 'ApplicationClass' not found.

My goal is to find the last row of data in Column A, and then take all cells starting A4 and do .columns.autofit on all columns starting A4 The reason why I'm doing that is because cells A1 - A3 have some long text values in them and I want them to be as they are.

Code:

```
Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Dim _excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()
Dim lRow As Long
With wSheet
     lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(_excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
     .Range("A4" & lRow).Columns.AutoFit()
End With
```

Comment: `XlDirection` is not a member of the Application, it's a member of the *namespace*.  Just look at in in the Object Browser.

Comment: @comintern - I have Micorosft Excel 12.0 Checked in my references however, in that same function I'm passing DataTable as a parameter and it's saying DataTable is an ambiguous name...

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with the question.  `_excel.XlDirection.xlUp` should be `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp`.

Comment: that seems to accept it but is .range part okay because it doesn't autofit still @Comintern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original error was due to the fact that `XlDirection` is an enumeration in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` *namespace* - it isn't a member of `Excel.Application`.  The bit `_excel.XlDirection.xlUp` should be:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp
```

The second issue is that the Range you build here...

> ```
>  lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(_excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
>  .Range("A4" & lRow).Columns.AutoFit()
> ```

...just appends a row number to the end of "A4".  So if the last row was 42, the range you would auto-fit would be "A442".  It needs to be `("A4:A" & lRow)`.

But that still only auto-fits column A. If that's your intent, stop here.  If you need to auto-fit *all* the columns (as indicated by the phrase "all ***columns*** starting A4" - my emphasis), read on.

First, you don't need to find the last row number - you're working with *Columns* when you're performing your auto-fit, so `Rows.Count` works as well as anything else. You really need to find the right-most *column*, but I'd skip all of that and just offset the used range down by 3 rows:

```
With wSheet
     .UsedRange.Offset(3).Columns.AutoFit
End With
```